# QuickTest Pro -- deploying/running tests for execution on multiple VMs

Tags: testing, qtp

I am new to QTP, so apologise for what might be a daft question.

I am writing automated GUI tests using QTP but wish to execute them on a number of test VMs.

Does QTP have some kind of "lightweight" agent that I can push to each test VM, rather than install the full QTP product? These test VMs are regularly rebuilt, so having to go through the pain of a full QTP install on each one every time they are rebuilt would become very timeconsuming.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a daft question at all, unfortunately the answer is *no*, there is no lightweight version of QTP for test execution.

If you want to avoid the pain of re-installing QTP every time a VM is deployed I can suggest one of two options.

- Save a snapshot of the VM with QTP installed
- Hook up QTP's silent installation as a VM task which is part of the VM deployment process